# Is it safe to upgrade Ubuntu on Dell Vostro V130?

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, hardware, dell

I just bought a Dell Vostro V130 notebook for my girlfriend, and I wanted to keep the preinstalled Ubuntu, at least for a while (and then, if needed, replace it with OpenSuSe).

But since the preinstalled version is 10.04 I wanted to at least install the current version. Is it safe? The notebook seems to be only certified for the preinstalled 10.04 version (and nothing else).

Is there some HW blob that only exists in the preinstalled version that is preventing the normal (and current) version to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the upgrade and it seemed to have worked.

`dell-laptop-dkms` package failed to upgrade to the new kernel (and I have no idea where to get it in a newer version), but the system seems to be working anyway (haven't noticed anything missing yet).